# How can i clip a larger raster image to a smaller image using rasterio or other libraries in python?

Tags: gis, clip, rasterio

I have a raster image of rather larger area but i am struggling to write about a program that can help me clip the image. how should i go about doing it and what would be needed.

I tried few lines of code but did not work at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.